cp command gives preserving permissions for xxx Numerical result out of range
I performed the following command:
cp -pR /media/z/tmill xz

It returns with the error

cp: preserving permissions for ‘xz/tmill/ReplaceYourMotor.webm’:
Numerical result out of range

The directory is as follows (only one file in this example):
ls -l /media/z/tmill
total 57664
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 59048734 Jun 13  2022 ReplaceYourMotor.webm

I'm getting similar results on some other copies but not all. it's almost as if files with extension .webm are the only objectionable entries.
/media/z is provided by an NTFS mount which resides on a Windows XP system.  In XUbuntu (24.04), it is SAMBA mounted.
xz is a directory on an external USB harddrive formatted NTFS. It was mounted via Thunar, the XFCE GUI for XUbuntu (currently at 24.04).
The copy command (cp) is preserving the date/time of the original file(s).
What is the numerical value out of range and why?

What is the file system in use on the mounted drive in the media directory?

NTFS does not understand the permission attributes used by Linux. You need a Linux native file system like ext4 or zfs to copy the file permissions along with the files.
